# How to use templates and connect all components in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django and I'm having a somewhat hard time understanding how to connect all of the different pieces together. All of the tutorials I've read on Django templates don't explain how to connect all of the pieces.

I have created my base template called base.html. I have a couple functions inside my views.py class that do specific things. Now I want to create pages that inherit from base.html and display information with respect to each function. So say I want action1.html to call the action_one function and action2.html to call the action_two function. I don't really get how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for pasting image but this can help you understand how the flow goes: 
[image]

there are lots of things going on but i didnot draw them so you can see how the basic flow goes.

for the red part, you can use `render_to_response` as Thomas says. but i would use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) as Kevin does.

here the difference:

> render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

hope this helps a bit

Comment: @foadster my pleasure. feel free to ask if you need help

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how Django templates and views interact: in Django, *views render templates*, not the other way around (i.e. *templates do not call views*).

One example of a view rendering a template is the [`render_to_response` helper function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response).

As for what defines what view is called when a given URL is accessed, this is your [URL configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

The following is probably where you want to start here:

- In your URL configuration, map the `/action_one/` URL to the `action_one` view.
- In your `action_one` view, render the `action_one.html` template

Comment: Yeah I get how to use the URL configuration to call specific views. I'm not understanding how to render my template though.

Comment: @foadster Use `render_to_response('template_name.html')`, or `render('...')` to render a template. There are other ways, but these are the most straightforward one. Are you using class-based views or regular views?

Comment: I don't know...I'm not using my models directly if that's what you're asking. I'm requesting data using my models and massaging my data. The data then gets put into a list. I want to display that list of data on my webpage

Comment: @foadster Data (like this list) is passed from a view to a template in the *`context`* that you pass to the `render` call.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this code example helps lay it out...

## urls.py

```
url(r'^action1/$', 'yourapp.views.action1'),
url(r'^action2/$', 'yourapp.views.action2'),
```

## views.py

```
def action1(request):
    return render(request, 'action1.html')

def action2(request):
    return render(request, 'action2.html')
```

## base.html

```
<html>
...stuff...
<body>
{% block action %}
{% endblock action %}
</body>
</html>
```

## action1.html

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block action %}
    ... action1 html stuff ...
{% endblock action %}
```

## action2.html

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block action %}
    ... action2 html stuff ...
{% endblock action %}
```

Comment: No problem at all!  Hope it helps :)